# Mysql query string for photo sharing social app like Instagram

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sharing

I am developing a photo sharing app platform. The app allows you to post a photo and others can like or rate the photo. Users can follow each other and see photos their 'followings' are sharing, just like instagram.

```
 #user_tbl
id | name | number
-------------------
 1 | Dan  | 0209
 2 | Sam  | 2854
 3 | Dave | 8123
 4 | Alex | 5600

#photo_tbl
id | userid | path
-------------------
 1 |  3     | dave-dog.jpg
 2 |  1     | dans-cat.png
 3 |  4     | alex-bird.jpg
 4 |  2     | sam-fish.jpg


#friendship_tbl
id | actor | target
--------------------
 1 |  2    | 1   // Sam is following Sam
 2 |  2    | 4   // Sam is following Alex
 3 |  1    | 3   // Dan is following Dave
 4 |  4    | 2   // Alex is following Sam

 #activities_stream_tbl
id | photoid | userid | context               | date
----------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   3     |  4     | add-new-photo         | 10/10/2015
 2 |   1     |  3     | add-new-photo         | 12/10/2015
 3 |   3     |  2     | Sam-share-Alex-photo  | 15/10/2015
 4 |   4     |  2     | add-new-photo         | 20/10/2015
 6 |   1     |  1     | Dan-like-Dave-photo   | 21/10/2015
```

The #user_table holds the basic info of a user, while `#photo_tbl` hold the name and path of the photo shared by the user. In the `#friendship_tbl` is the relationship link between users. `"actor"` column is the id of the user doing the following while `"target"` column is the id of the user being followed.

I am currently having problem writing a query string to pull photos of `USERX` and photos of other users `USERX` is following and GROUP them by "photoid" in the activities_stream_tbl and ORDER BY "date" activities_stream_tbl.

I will be glad if anyone can help me, show me a better way of structuring db thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to pull photos of USERX, you can construct your sql like

```
select PATH
from user_tbl as a inner join photo_tbl as b 
on a.id = b.user_id
and a.name = 'userx'
```

and to pull photos of other users USERX is following, you may write

```
select path
from photo_tbl as a
where a.userid in (select target from friendship_tbl as x inner join user_tbl as y on x.actor = y.id and y.name = 'user')
```

you can union the above two results if you want.

ex:

```
select PATH
from user_tbl as a inner join photo_tbl as b 
on a.id = b.user_id
and a.name = 'userx'
   UNION
select path
from photo_tbl as a
where a.userid in (select target 
                   from   friendship_tbl as x 
                   inner  join user_tbl as y 
                     on   x.actor = y.id and y.name = 'user')
```

Comment: thank you @PK20, how can i put the two queries into one query string.